# Solr - Get n elements before and after certain element (given a query)

Tags: solr, pagination

i'm building a page with Apache Solr, where i show an image (with a specific solr ID) selected from a serp. The serp can be optional, this mean that there isn't a query that generate it (like the case where you share an image), and the recommended elements would be extracted analyzing the image.
But if a query exists, i should extract some recommended elements using possibly the same query. Now, how can i extract the first 5 elements before the selected, and the first five elements after the selected? This should follow the pagination order (in the serp).

An example:

```
Page 1 contains: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Page 2 contains: 14, 22, 33, 44, 55, 84, 12, 57
```

---

```
You have selected: 8 (which is in page 1)
```

---

```
Expected recommended elements:
BEFORE: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 (or inverse order, this is indifferent)
AFTER: 9, 10, 14, 22, 33
```

Different queries can be executed, this is not a problem. Anyone know how can i approach this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two queries. One to retrieve the hits in front, one to retrieve the hits after. As the query and filters will be cached, performance shouldn't be an issue.